# JavaScript application bug: calling a function inside another throws a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of Bootstrap 4 cards, displayed on the 12 columns grid.

I have made a **filter by year** and a **search-box**. As can be seen in the example below, the search expression is matched against the title of each card and the selected year is matched against the value of the `data-year` attribute.

```js
class CardsFilteringComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.filterableCardsList = document.querySelector('.filterableItems');
    this.items = this.filterableCardsList.querySelectorAll('.card-container');
    this.searchBox = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#searchBoxInput');
    this.searchBtn = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#searchBoxSubmitBtn');
    this.selectBox = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#selectYear');
    this.isHiddenClass = 'd-none';
  }

  handleSearchButtonClick(target) {
    // call the filter function
    //this.handleSelectChange(target);
    const expression = this.searchBox.value.toLowerCase();

    [...this.items].forEach(item => {
      const cardTitle = item.querySelector('.title').textContent;
      const showItem = cardTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(expression) > -1;
      const method = showItem ? 'remove' : 'add';
      item.classList[method](this.isHiddenClass);
    });
  }

  handleSelectChange(target) {
    // call the search function
    //this.handleSearchButtonClick(target);
    const {value } = target;

    [...this.items].forEach(item => {
      const year = item.dataset.year;
      const showItem = year === value || value === 'ALL';
      const method = showItem ? 'remove' : 'add';
      item.classList[method](this.isHiddenClass);
    });
  }

  init() {
    this.searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.handleSearchButtonClick();
    });

    this.searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        this.handleSearchButtonClick();
      }
    });

    this.selectBox.addEventListener('change', e => {
      this.handleSelectChange(e.target);
    });
  }
}
const cardsFilteringComponent = new CardsFilteringComponent();
cardsFilteringComponent.init();
```

```css
.cards-grid>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.cards-grid .card {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="filterableItems my-4">
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="searchBoxInput">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="searchBoxSubmitBtn" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <select id="selectYear" class="form-control">
        <option value="ALL" selected>All</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row cards-grid">
      <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2019">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="cardImage">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=north" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="cardContent p-3">
            <h5 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat voluptates modi hic molestias quam doloremque. Accusantium odio blanditiis, amet placeat distinctio, quam magni, nobis perferendis error dicta perspiciatis quod delectus.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2019</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2020">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="cardImage">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=south" alt="In, quod adipisci" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="cardContent p-3">
            <h5 class="title">In, quod adipisci</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia eaque qui ipsa quod facere autem voluptatem.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 3<sup>rd</sup> 2020</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2021">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="cardImage">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=west" alt="Pariatur, sit, dolor" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="cardContent p-3">
            <h5 class="title">Pariatur, sit, dolor</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum eaque repellat cumque pariatur dolores enim quibusdam nemo distinctio, dolore incidunt cupiditate ea excepturi est architecto amet tempore voluptatibus alias doloremque.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2021</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### The problem

Besides making these two filters work on their own, I need to make them work together: if I do a search followed by a filtering, only the search results should be filtered by year.

For this purpose I *call each method inside the other* one, as can be seen in the commented out lines `//this.handleSearchButtonClick(target)` and `//this.handleSelectChange(target)`.

This results in the error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

See the error in **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Ajax30/L5me3yh1/5/)** fiddle.

I am looking for an elegant, non-hack, solution.

#### Questions:

1. Where is my mistake?
2. What is the optimal, non-hack fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is your you are calling one function that is calling the other function which in turns calls the original function and this goes on until `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error is raised.

What you could do instead is: save the values of both filters and apply them simultaneously.

```js
  handleSearchButtonClick(target) {
    const expression = this.searchBox.value.toLowerCase();
    
    this.filters.search = expression; // save the expression
    this.applyFilter();
  }

  handleSelectChange(target) {
    const {value} = target;

    this.filters.year = value; // save the year
    this.applyFilter();
  }

  applyFilter() {
     // For each item

     // Filter by title first
     const cardTitle = ...;
     const showItemForSearch = cardTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filters.search) > -1;
      
     // Filter by year next
     const year = ...;
     const showItemForYear = year === this.filters.year || this.filters.year === 'ALL';
     
     // make it visible if both condition is met
     const showItem = showItemForSearch && showItemForYear;
     ...
   });
 }
```

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ra4y0cz/1/

```js
class CardsFilteringComponent {
constructor() {
    this.isHiddenClass = 'd-none';

    this.filterableCardsList = document.querySelector('.filterableItems');
    this.items = this.filterableCardsList.querySelectorAll('.card-container');

    // saving the initial or default values of the filters
    this.filters = {
        search: '',
        year: 'ALL'
    };

    // saving each item into an array
    // makes it easier to manipulate the state of each item i.e. hidden or visible
    this.state = [];
    this.items.forEach(item => {
        this.state.push({
            node: item,
            hidden: false // initially saving all items as visible, will modify this later
        });
    });


    this.searchBox = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#searchBoxInput');
    this.searchBtn = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#searchBoxSubmitBtn');
    this.selectBox = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#selectYear');

    this.render(); // initial rendering, all items are visible
}

render() {
    // reading value from the state array and applying classname according to .hidden property
    this.state.forEach(item => {
        const method = item.hidden ? 'add' : 'remove';
        item.node.classList[method](this.isHiddenClass);
    });
}

applyFilter() {
    this.state.forEach(item => {
        // Filter by title first
        const cardTitle = item.node.querySelector('.title').textContent;
        const showItemForSearch = cardTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filters.search) > -1;

        // Filter by year next
        const year = item.node.dataset.year;
        const showItemForYear = year === this.filters.year || this.filters.year === 'ALL';

        // make it visible if both condition is met
        // .hidden is the opposite of that
        item.hidden = !(showItemForSearch && showItemForYear);
    });
    this.render(); // re-render since the state array may have changed
}

handleSearchButtonClick(target) {
    const expression = this.searchBox.value.toLowerCase();
    this.filters.search = expression; // save the expression
    
    this.applyFilter();
}

handleSelectChange(target) {
    const { value } = target;
    this.filters.year = value; // save the year
    
    this.applyFilter();
}

init() {
    this.searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.handleSearchButtonClick();
    });

    this.searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            this.handleSearchButtonClick();
        }
    });

    this.selectBox.addEventListener('change', e => {
        this.handleSelectChange(e.target);
    });
}
}
const cardsFilteringComponent = new CardsFilteringComponent();
cardsFilteringComponent.init();
```

Comment: I thinks it does work. Give me some time to test it and I come back for the reward you deserve. :)

Comment: I would appreciate comments (in the code) that would help me understand what you did and why. Thank you!

Comment: Added comments in the collapsed code snippet at the bottom. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

you just have a recursive infinitive loop

```
function a(){ b();}
function b(){ a();}


a(); // recurisive infinite loop
```

You can prevent this by adding boolean condition

```
function a(guard){ if(!guard) b(true);}
function b(guard){ if(!guard) a(true);}

a();
```

Answer (score 1):

maximum callstack? you must have infinite loop or something like that- in your code its quite simple: you use function which use function which use the same function which called it

in your case- handleSelectChange triggers handleSearchButtonClick (on second line of this function body), and what handleSearchButtonClick does? boom! on the second line of its body: handleSelectChange

so you've done something like A triggers B, which triggers A, which triggers B and so on- perpetuum mobile

so maybe something in this manner (I didn't test that! Just pseudocode)?

```
handleSearchButtonClick(target, fromOtherHandler = false) {
  if (!fromOtherHandler) this.handleSelectChange(target, true);
  /*rest of the function body*/
}
handleSelectChange(target, fromOtherHandler = false) {
  if (!fromOtherHandler) this.handleSearchButtonClick(target, true);
  /*rest of the function body*/
}
```

also you must change in init

```
this.searchBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  this.handleSearchButtonClick(e.target);
});
```

so its will work just from event (so once) but not from function itself (many times)

in theory of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to simplify the flow of your code. Whenever you combine Filters with Search, You think of the flow as

- Step 1 :  User "Enters Text"
- Step 2 : User "Filters" on results

However, this should translate to,

- Step 1 : When user clicks search button, inspect for any filter.
- Step 2 : Combine Filter params into "query string" (Even if empty, pass in empty filter).
- Step 3 : Hit API with "text + filter" in query.
- Step 4 : When user updates filter, Go to Step 2.

This approach avoids short-circuiting the call by using an additional flag as suggested in some of the other responses here.

Here is an updated snippet which will help achieve this.

```js
class CardsFilteringComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.filterableCardsList = document.querySelector('.filterableItems');
    this.items = this.filterableCardsList.querySelectorAll('.card-container');
    this.searchBox = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#searchBoxInput');
    this.searchBtn = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#searchBoxSubmitBtn');
    this.selectBox = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#selectYear');
    this.isHiddenClass = 'd-none';
    this.filter = {};
  }

  isItemFiltered(item) {
    const filters = Object.entries(this.filter);

    let isFiltered = true;

    filters.forEach(([key, value]) => {
      isFiltered = isFiltered && item.dataset[key] == value
    });

    return isFiltered;
  }

  handleSearchButtonClick(target) {
    // call the filter function
    //this.handleSelectChange(target);
    const expression = this.searchBox.value.toLowerCase();

    [...this.items].forEach(item => {

      const cardTitle = item.querySelector('.title').textContent;
      const showItem = cardTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(expression) > -1 && this.isItemFiltered(item);
      const method = showItem ? 'remove' : 'add';

      item.classList[method](this.isHiddenClass);
    });
  }



  handleSelectChange(target) {
    // call the search function
    //this.handleSearchButtonClick(target);
    const {
      value
    } = target;

    // [...this.items].forEach(item => {
    //   const year = item.dataset.year;
    //   const showItem = year === value || value === 'ALL';
    //   const method = showItem ? 'remove' : 'add';
    //   item.classList[method](this.isHiddenClass);
    // });
    if (value == 'ALL') {
      delete this.filter['year'];
    } else {
      this.filter['year'] = value;
    }
    this.handleSearchButtonClick();
  }

  init() {
    this.searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.handleSearchButtonClick();
    });

    this.searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        this.handleSearchButtonClick();
      }
    });

    this.selectBox.addEventListener('change', e => {
      this.handleSelectChange(e.target);
    });
  }
}
const cardsFilteringComponent = new CardsFilteringComponent();
cardsFilteringComponent.init();
```

```css
.cards-grid>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.cards-grid .card {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="filterableItems my-4">
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="searchBoxInput">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="searchBoxSubmitBtn" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <select id="selectYear" class="form-control">
        <option value="ALL" selected>All</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row cards-grid">
      <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2019">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="cardImage">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=north" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="cardContent p-3">
            <h5 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat voluptates modi hic molestias quam doloremque. Accusantium odio blanditiis, amet placeat distinctio, quam magni, nobis perferendis error dicta perspiciatis quod delectus.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2019</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2020">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="cardImage">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=north" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="cardContent p-3">
            <h5 class="title">Lorem jagz dolor</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat voluptates modi hic molestias quam doloremque. Accusantium odio blanditiis, amet placeat distinctio, quam magni, nobis perferendis error dicta perspiciatis quod delectus.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2020</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2020">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="cardImage">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=north" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="cardContent p-3">
            <h5 class="title">Lorem jag dolor</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat voluptates modi hic molestias quam doloremque. Accusantium odio blanditiis, amet placeat distinctio, quam magni, nobis perferendis error dicta perspiciatis quod delectus.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2020</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2020">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="cardImage">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=south" alt="In, quod adipisci" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="cardContent p-3">
            <h5 class="title">In, quod adipisci</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia eaque qui ipsa quod facere autem voluptatem.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 3<sup>rd</sup> 2020</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2021">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="cardImage">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=west" alt="Pariatur, sit, dolor" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="cardContent p-3">
            <h5 class="title">Pariatur, sit, dolor</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum eaque repellat cumque pariatur dolores enim quibusdam nemo distinctio, dolore incidunt cupiditate ea excepturi est architecto amet tempore voluptatibus alias doloremque.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2021</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2021">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cardImage">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=west" alt="Pariatur, sit, dolor" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="cardContent p-3">
          <h5 class="title">Pariatur, Jagz, dolor</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum eaque repellat cumque pariatur dolores enim quibusdam nemo distinctio, dolore incidunt cupiditate ea excepturi est architecto amet tempore voluptatibus alias doloremque.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2021</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a version to which I have added a message for when **no results** are returned from the search/filter:

```js
class CardsFilteringComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.isHiddenClass = 'd-none';
    this.noResults = document.querySelector('#noResults');
    this.filterableCardsList = document.querySelector('.filterableItems');
    this.items = this.filterableCardsList.querySelectorAll('.card-container');
    
    this.filters = {
        search: '',
      year: 'ALL'
    };
    this.state = [];
    this.items.forEach(item => {
      this.state.push({
                node: item,
        hidden: false
      });
    });
    
    
    this.searchBox = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#searchBoxInput');
    this.searchBtn = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#searchBoxSubmitBtn');
    this.selectBox = this.filterableCardsList.querySelector('#selectYear');
    this.render();
  }
  
  render() {
    const visibleItems = [];
    
    this.state.forEach(item => {
      const method = item.hidden ? 'add' : 'remove';
      item.node.classList[method](this.isHiddenClass);
      if(!item.hidden){
        visibleItems.push(item);
      }
    });
    
    if(!visibleItems.length){
        this.noResults.classList.remove('d-none');
    } else {
        this.noResults.classList.add('d-none');
    }
  }
  
  applyFilter() {
     this.state.forEach(item => {
      const cardTitle = item.node.querySelector('.title').textContent;
      const showItemForSearch = cardTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filters.search) > -1;
      const year = item.node.dataset.year;
      const showItemForYear = year === this.filters.year || this.filters.year === 'ALL';
      item.hidden = !(showItemForSearch && showItemForYear);
    });
    this.render();
  }

  handleSearchButtonClick(target) {
    const expression = this.searchBox.value.toLowerCase();
    this.filters.search = expression;
    this.applyFilter();
  }

  handleSelectChange(target) {
    const {value} = target;

    this.filters.year = value;
    this.applyFilter();
  }

  init() {
    this.searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.handleSearchButtonClick();
    });

    this.searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        this.handleSearchButtonClick();
      }
    });

    this.selectBox.addEventListener('change', e => {
      this.handleSelectChange(e.target);
    });
  }
}
const cardsFilteringComponent = new CardsFilteringComponent();
cardsFilteringComponent.init();
```

```css
.cards-grid > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.cards-grid .card {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="filterableItems my-4">
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="searchBoxInput">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="searchBoxSubmitBtn" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <select id="selectYear" class="form-control">
        <option value="ALL" selected>All</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row cards-grid">
      <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2019">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="cardImage">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=north" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="cardContent p-3">
            <h5 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat voluptates modi hic molestias quam doloremque. Accusantium odio blanditiis, amet placeat distinctio, quam magni, nobis perferendis error dicta perspiciatis quod delectus.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2019</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2020">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="cardImage">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=south" alt="In, quod adipisci" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="cardContent p-3">
            <h5 class="title">In, quod adipisci</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia eaque qui ipsa quod facere autem voluptatem.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 3<sup>rd</sup> 2020</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-year="2021">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="cardImage">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=west" alt="Pariatur, sit, dolor" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="cardContent p-3">
            <h5 class="title">Pariatur, sit, dolor</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum eaque repellat cumque pariatur dolores enim quibusdam nemo distinctio, dolore incidunt cupiditate ea excepturi est architecto amet tempore voluptatibus alias doloremque.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-3 text-right text-muted small">Published on January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2021</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-none p-2 text-center text-muted" id="noResults">No results</div>
  </div>
</div>
```